# Fatal error: Uncaught Google_Service_Exception Google Sheets API PHP Error Adding Row

Tags: php, google-sheets-api

Getting the following error:

`Fatal error: Uncaught Google_Service_Exception: { "error": { "code": 400, "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"0\" at 'data.values[1]': Cannot find field.`

Weirdly it only happens when the array I am adding has from the 7th index on. See full array below.

```
array (size=11)
      0 => int 2176
      1 => string '16 Bedroom Residence With Unique Design' (length=39)
      2 => string 'This residence has a proven solid rental income... (length=2224)
      3 => string '2095000' (length=7)
      4 => string '3000' (length=4)
      5 => string '16' (length=2)
      6 => string '16.5' (length=4)
      7 => string 'Tamarindo' (length=9)
      8 => string 'For Sale' (length=8)
      9 => string 'House' (length=5)
      10 => string 'Air Conditioning, BBQ Area, Close to Schools, Close to Shops, Fully Equipped, Fully Furnished, Internet / Wifi, Laundry Room, Parking, Private Garden, Private Pool, ' (length=165)
```

Here is the function I call to add the rows:

```
function insert_google_sheet($data)
{

    require 'vendor/autoload.php';

    $client = new  \Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName('Properties Google Sheet');
    $client->setScopes([\Google_Service_Sheets::SPREADSHEETS]);
    $client->setAccessType('offline');
    $client->setAuthConfig(__DIR__ . '/credentials.json');
    $service = new Google_Service_Sheets($client);
    $spreadsheetID = '1_3o2B7kucFBNWLJ99CWKCJsePqfZgB2fi8U7AatFoow';

    $range = 'Properties';

    $body = new Google_Service_Sheets_ValueRange([
        'values'    => $data
    ]);
    $params = [
        'valueInputOption' => 'RAW'
    ];
    $insert = [
        'insertDataOption'  => 'INSERT_ROWS'
    ];
    $service->spreadsheets_values->append($spreadsheetID, $range, $body, $params, $insert);

}
```

I repeat, it works well if I only have up to the sixth index in the array.

________EDIT____________

Gathering data to insert in Google Sheets form wordpress post

```
$insert_data = [];
    // Get Post Info
    $properties = get_posts(array(
        'numberposts'      => -1,
        'orderby'          => 'title',
        'order'            => 'ASC',
        'post_type'        => 'property',
    ));

    foreach ($properties as $property) {
        // Get Post Meta    
        $id = $property->ID;
        $title = $property->post_title;
        $description =  $property->post_content;

        $property_meta = get_post_meta($id);
        $price = $property_meta['_meta_price'][0];
        $area =   $property_meta['_meta_area'][0];
        $beds = $property_meta['_meta_bedroom'][0];
        $baths = $property_meta['_meta_bathroom'][0];
        // $featured = $property_meta['_meta_featured'][0];

        $property_location = get_the_terms($id, 'location');
        $property_location = $property_location[0]->name;

        $property_status = get_the_terms($id, 'status');
        $property_status = $property_status[0]->name;

        $property_type = get_the_terms($id, 'type');
        $property_type = $property_type[0]->name;

        $property_features = get_the_terms($id, 'features');

        if ($property_features) {
            $features = '';
            foreach ($property_features as $feat) {
                $features .=  $feat->name . ', ';
            }
        }

        $data_array = array(
            $id,
            $title,
            $description,
            $price,
            $area,
            $beds,
            $baths,
            $property_location,
            $property_status,
            $property_type,
            $features
        );
        array_push($insert_data, $data_array);
    }

    insert_google_sheet($insert_data);
```

Comment: Can you provide the sample value of `$data` for replicating your issue?

Comment: @Tanaike I have just added the code I am using to set `$data`, they come from Wordpress post.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I couldn't image about the sample values of `$data` from your additional script. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. I think that I have to study more. And when I could image it, I would like to think of your issue and solution.

Comment: As @Tanaike has said, maybe you could post some information about the value of `$data` to help us debug your problem. Just so you can double check it, look for [the endpoint](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append) and see if maybe you are not enforming the request in the corect format.

Comment: My first block of code is the array I am passing as `$data`.

Comment: One more weird thing. I can insert the data individually. It only shows the error when I have the full `$data_array`. Weird!

Comment: Why are you using the variable `"Properties"` as `range` parameter. I think this is not the expected value that the endpoint is expecting. All other stuff seems find, take a look at the [`endpoint`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append) the A1 notation is the expected value. If `Properties` is your sheet change the value to `Porperties!A:Z`.

Answer (score 2):

It is objecting to some of the incoming data, but the error message isn't any clearer than that. The `Unknown name \"0\" at 'data.values[0]': Cannot find field.` is a misdirection. It's not necessarily the [0] value that is a problem. My problem was a NULL value in [7] in row 3. If you are passing multiple rows in $insert_data, a problem in any of them might be the issue. It would be the same error message.

Perhaps the sheet expects a number in that column? Try a different, blank worksheet?

Comment: I found that if I send one property at time it works and also that $data_array is not so big too. It seems to me to be related to the size of information we send to Google Sheets? It does not make sense why that would be but reading `Invalid JSON payload received` makes me believe that. There is a `payload` limit there!?!?